# How to: LinkedIn api with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use the LinkedIn api with JavaScript(I'm new to it...).
Here is my simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log("onSuccess() " + data);
        console.log(data);
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log("onError() " + JSON.stringify(error));
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
    function getProfileData() {
        console.log(IN.User.isAuthorized());
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }

</script>

<script type="in/Login">
    Welcome, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I took it almost as is from the documentation. 
I see the prints but I don't see the profile. What am I'm doing wrong?
I've wrote the Valid SDK Domain as http://localhost:63342/ because that's what the WebStorm uses.

P.S. I also get "Unresolved variable or type..." warning\error for IN,API, Even and Raw.

Update:
I see in browser console:

```
message:"Could not find person based on: ~"
requestId:"4VCQPKNS5G"
status:404
timestamp:1477219009923
```

It seems to me that the authentication part goes well, but it fails somewhere else after that...

Update2:
I've changed the code a little bit, mostly to use console.log instead of document.write and added additional log for IN.User.isAuthorized().

Comment: Did you authorize the app (via login popup)? I see no calls to `IN.User.authorize()`. If not, what caused `getProfileData()` to run?

Comment: From my understanding getProfileData() is called from onLinkedInLoad, and the authorization happens because of authorize: true and I added document.write(IN.User.isAuthorized() + "<br>"); to the getProfileData() which returns true.

Comment: First, try to avoid `document.write()` in favor of `console.log()`, `console.warn()`, ect. Try to log the user out (`IN.User.logout()` from the console) and then `IN.User.authorize(callbackFunction, callbackScope);`. It should create a popup and allow you to log in and authorize the app.

Comment: I mean it looks as is "/people/~" is being parsed as the person `~` in the `people` resource. The error it is giving is that it doesn't know how to use `~` to resolve a person.

Comment: @MasterAM, I've updated the code and tried to run IN.User.logout(); and IN.User.authorize(callbackFunction, callbackScope); from the chrome console but I get errors for the second one: Uncaught ReferenceError: callbackFunction is not defined(…).

Comment: This is a function signature. You need to supply a callback that would be called once the user is authenticated and, optionally, a parameter that would be used as the scope of this callback.

Comment: @christopher, I took the code as is from the documentation: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

Comment: @MasterAM, my bad I just got it. I've changed it to: IN.User.authorize(getProfileData); and this time I did get the popup but after I sign in I still get the same error("Could not find person based on: ~").

Comment: Then I have no idea why you get this response, although I could find references for it. Perhaps your user is missing some of the default fields (for me: first name, last name, headline (position at company)). And please, don't take this code as any example of what a modern JavaScript application should look like today.

Comment: Where did you find a reference for it?

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this problem i'm having it now and i can't work it out